# Filtering documents on global and local level with html and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently Im struggling with html, css and js code amd I have no idea how to make it working properly. Partially my requirements are covered but not as supposed.

My requirements:

- Buttons with global filters, after clicking one of them filters are applied for all elements with class document new/removed/changed.
- Unclicking button, removes filter
- Button with local filters applicable only in div id area

Current issues:

- Button highlight working only for global button
- global filters don't work
- sometimes I have to press button twice till filter will be applicable

```js
let activeFilter = null;

function toggleFilter(filter, containerId) {
  const filterButton = document.querySelector(`.filter-button[data-filter="${filter}"]`);
  const container = containerId ? document.getElementById(containerId) : document;

  if (!containerId || activeFilter === filter) {
    filterButton.classList.remove('active');
    activeFilter = null;
    showAllDocuments(container);
  } else {
    if (activeFilter) {
      const activeFilterButton = document.querySelector(`.filter-button[data-filter="${activeFilter}"]`);
      activeFilterButton.classList.remove('active');
    }

    filterButton.classList.add('active');
    activeFilter = filter;
    filterDocuments(container);
  }
}

function showAllDocuments(container) {
  const documents = container.querySelectorAll('.document');
  documents.forEach(doc => doc.classList.remove('hide'));
}

function filterDocuments(container) {
  const documents = container.querySelectorAll('.document');
  documents.forEach(doc => {
    const docClass = doc.classList[1];
    if (docClass === activeFilter || activeFilter === null) {
      doc.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      doc.classList.add('hide');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.filter-button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.document {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.new.hide,
.change.hide,
.removed.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '')">Document New global</button>
  <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change' ,'')">Document Change global</button>
  <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '')">Document Removed global</button>

  <div id="1">
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '1')">Document New local</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change', '1')">Document Change local</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '1')">Document Removed local</button>
    <div class="document new">Document 1 (New)</div>
    <div class="document change">Document 2 (Change)</div>
    <div class="document removed">Document 3 (Removed)</div>
  </div>

  <div id="2">
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '2')">Document New local</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change', '2')">Document Change local</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '2')">Document Removed local</button>
    <div class="document new">Document 1 (New)</div>
    <div class="document change">Document 2 (Change)</div>
    <div class="document removed">Document 3 (Removed)</div>
  </div>

  <div id="3">
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '3')">Document New local</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change', '3')">Document Change local</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '3')">Document Removed local</button>
    <div class="document new">Document 1 (New)</div>
    <div class="document change">Document 2 (Change)</div>
    <div class="document removed">Document 3 (Removed)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I've developed code working almost as was suppose. Maybe there is a small issue with button highlighting but I can take it as is :)

```js
let lastFilterType = '';
  let lastDivId = '';

  function toggleFilter(filterType, divId) {
    const containers = divId === '' ? document.querySelectorAll('.document') : document.getElementById(divId).querySelectorAll('.document');
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-button');

    if (lastFilterType === filterType && divId === lastDivId) {
      containers.forEach(document => {
        document.style.display = 'block';
      });
      buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.style.backgroundColor = '';
      });
      lastFilterType = '';
    } else {
      lastFilterType = filterType;
      lastDivId = divId;

      containers.forEach(document => {
        const documentClassList = document.classList;
        document.style.display = filterType === '' || documentClassList.contains(filterType) ? 'block' : 'none';
      });

      buttons.forEach(button => {
        const dataFilter = button.getAttribute('data-filter');
        const buttonId = button.parentElement.id;

        if (
          (filterType === '' || filterType === dataFilter) &&
          (divId === '' || (divId === buttonId && filterType !== ''))
        ) {
          button.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        } else {
          button.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```css
        .filter-button {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }


        .document {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '')">Document New global</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change' ,'')">Document Change global</button>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '')">Document Removed global</button>

    <div id="1">
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '1')">Document New local</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change', '1')">Document Change local</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '1')">Document Removed local</button>
        <div class="document new">Document 1 (New)</div>
        <div class="document change">Document 2 (Change)</div>
        <div class="document removed">Document 3 (Removed)</div>
    </div>

    <div id="2">
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '2')">Document New local</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change', '2')">Document Change local</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '2')">Document Removed local</button>
        <div class="document new">Document 1 (New)</div>
        <div class="document change">Document 2 (Change)</div>
        <div class="document removed">Document 3 (Removed)</div>
    </div>

    <div id="3">
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="new" onclick="toggleFilter('new', '3')">Document New local</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="change" onclick="toggleFilter('change', '3')">Document Change local</button>
        <button class="filter-button" data-filter="removed" onclick="toggleFilter('removed', '3')">Document Removed local</button>
        <div class="document new">Document 1 (New)</div>
        <div class="document change">Document 2 (Change)</div>
        <div class="document removed">Document 3 (Removed)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I optimized  the `toggleFilter`  by distinguishing between `global` and `local` filters. So it requires checking if a `container ID` is provided and handling the filter application accordingly. This update function should now distinguish between the global and local filters based on the `containerId`. If containerId is empty then it's a global filter else it's local.

```
let activeGlobalFilter = null;
let activeLocalFilters = {};

function toggleFilter(filter, containerId) {
  const isGlobal = !containerId; // Check if containerId is not provided for global filters
  const activeFilterKey = isGlobal ? 'global' : containerId;
  let activeFilter = isGlobal ? activeGlobalFilter : activeLocalFilters[containerId];

  const filterButtonsSelector = isGlobal ? `.filter-button[data-filter="${filter}"]` : `#${containerId} .filter-button[data-filter="${filter}"]`;
  const filterButtons = document.querySelectorAll(filterButtonsSelector);

  filterButtons.forEach(filterButton => {
    if (activeFilter === filter) {
      filterButton.classList.remove('active');
      if (isGlobal) {
        activeGlobalFilter = null;
      } else {
        activeLocalFilters[containerId] = null;
      }
      showAllDocuments(containerId);
    } else {
      if (activeFilter) {
        const activeButtonsSelector = isGlobal ? `.filter-button[data-filter="${activeFilter}"]` : `#${containerId} .filter-button[data-filter="${activeFilter}"]`;
        const activeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(activeButtonsSelector);
        activeButtons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'));
      }
      filterButton.classList.add('active');
      if (isGlobal) {
        activeGlobalFilter = filter;
      } else {
        activeLocalFilters[containerId] = filter;
      }
      filterDocuments(filter, containerId);
    }
  });
}

function showAllDocuments(containerId) {
  const container = containerId ? document.getElementById(containerId) : document;
  const documents = container.querySelectorAll('.document');
  documents.forEach(doc => doc.classList.remove('hide'));
}

function filterDocuments(filter, containerId) {
  const container = containerId ? document.getElementById(containerId) : document;
  const documents = container.querySelectorAll('.document');
  documents.forEach(doc => {
    if (doc.classList.contains(filter) || filter === null) {
      doc.classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      doc.classList.add('hide');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice try! Started working for global filters but stopped for local

Comment: I updated the code, hope it helps

Comment: Still local filter doesn't work.